# Display all inputs after all are entered

Tags: java, loops

I want to display all inputs after they have been entered. I don't want the loop to display the result after each input.

ex:

```
   input
   input
   input
```

```
   output
   output
   output
```

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arrayInt = new int[4];
        for (int i = 1; i <= arrayInt.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: \n");
            int numb = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i + "-" + " Your number is: " + numb);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run 2 separate loops for input and output.
Array index starts from 0.
Store each number in an array and then display it.

```
System.out.print("Enter a number: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
        arrayInt[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(i + "-" + " Your number is: " + arrayInt[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply modify your code like this

```
public class test { public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] arrayInt = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: \n");
        int numb = input.nextInt();
        arrayInt[i]=numb;
            

    }
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
            
       System.out.println((i+1) + "-" + " Your number is: " + arrayInt[i]);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are printing the values in each iteration of your loop after taking the input

To print them after taking inputs you just need to put the print statement in another loop and also it will be a good practice to set the counter to 0 for the first value like this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arrayInt = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: \n");
            arrayInt[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "-" + " Your number is: " + arrayInt[i]);
        }
    }
}
```